# Generating Swagger YAML from JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, yaml, swagger, jsdoc

I have a large JS API fully documented with JSDoc, and I am building a swagger based REST service to make the API available on a network.

I manually built an initial version of the YAML swagger spec, but the problem is that it rapidly gets out of sync with the JS API, because it is still evolving, specially in the properties of the objects involved.

What I would like to do is to automatically generate the swagger YAML, at least the data definition part of it, directly from the JSDoc comments. Is there any tool that can help me to automate it?

Answer (score 3):

[swagger-jsdoc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-jsdoc) may meet your requirement.

Comment: swagger-jsdoc actually has nothing to do with JSdocs. I don't know why it even uses the word jsdoc in it's name, it uses yaml in comments.